# iPad styling overwrites other styling

Tags: css

I am trying to create a website but when I reach the responsive section for tablets my previous codes get overwritten and it gets replaced with the tablet styling. How can I prevent this from happening? I also tried to use media queries orientation portrait and landscape but the styling for landscape view is not the way I wanted to be. I have placed a code from my tablet view so you can see what is the issue.

thank you have a nice day.

```
/* Moto G4, Galaxy S5 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }

  .index-form {
    width: 290px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .index-form .application {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .name .first-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .first-name .label-first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .first-name .label-first:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .first-name .input-first {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .name .last-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .last-name .label-last {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .last-name .label-last:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .last-name .input-last {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .index-form .contact {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .contact .phone-number {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .phone-number .label-phone {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .phone-number .label-phone:after {
    content: ":";
  }
  .phone-number .input-phone {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .contact .e-mail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .e-mail .label-email {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .e-mail .label-email:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .e-mail .input-email {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .index-form .location {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .location .address {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .address .label-address {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .address .label-address:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .address .input-address {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .zip-code {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .zip-code .label-zip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .zip-code .label-zip:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .zip-code .input-zip {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .location .city {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .city .label-city {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .city .label-city:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .city .input-city {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .state {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .state .label-state {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .state .label-state:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .state .select-state {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 44px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .index-form .position {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .position .label-position {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }

  .index-form .referance {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .referance .label-referance {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }

  .index-form .finish {
    width: 280px;
  }

  .finish .label-finish {
  }

  .finish .input-upload {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .finish .submit {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}


 /* IPad Pro */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }

  .index-form {
    width: 900px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .index-form .application {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 600px;
  }

  .name .first-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .first-name .label-first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .first-name .label-first:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .first-name .input-first {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .name .last-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .last-name .label-last {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .last-name .label-last:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .last-name .input-last {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .index-form .contact {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 600px;
  }

  .contact .phone-number {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .phone-number .label-phone {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .phone-number .label-phone:after {
    content: ":";
  }
  .phone-number .input-phone {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .contact .e-mail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .e-mail .label-email {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .e-mail .label-email:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .e-mail .input-email {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .index-form .location {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    width: 600px;
  }

  .location .address {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .address .label-address {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .address .label-address:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .address .input-address {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .zip-code {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .zip-code .label-zip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .zip-code .label-zip:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .zip-code .input-zip {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
  }

  .location .city {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .city .label-city {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .city .label-city:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .city .input-city {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 24px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .state {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .state .label-state {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .state .label-state:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .state .select-state {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 44px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .index-form .position {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .position .label-position {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }

  .index-form .referance {
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .referance .label-referance {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }
}
`
```

Comment: What styles are overwritten?

Comment: all styling from Moto G4 - iPhone X. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you show a media query for another device plus your default CSS and the order in which they come ( we don’t need all the settings).

Comment: I added the other code in the question.